# How to quickly find out where NAs are introduced?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with ground water data

```
df1 <- data.frame('ID' = c('r23', 'r24', 'r25', 'r26'),
                 'depth' = c("deep","deep","shallow","shallow"),
                 'conc1' = c("3.0", "<1.0", "2.5", "10.0"),
                 'conc2' = c(23, 45, 56, 12)
)
df2 <- data.frame('ID' = c('r27', 'r28', 'r29', 'r30'),
                 'depth2' = c("deep","shallow","shallow","deep"),
                 'conc1' = c(5.0, 3.4, 5.2, 1.2),
                 'conc2' = c(56, 76, 45, 23)
)
```

I define the numeric values like this to also catch the numerical variables with detection limits

```
num_vars_p <- names(df1 %>% select_if(function(x) is.numeric(x) | sum(grepl("<[0-9]", x)) > 0))
```

Then I fuse them like this:

```
pm <- full_join(df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)), 
            df2 %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)), 
            by = c("ID", "depth" = "depth2", "conc1", "conc2"),
            .keep_all = T) %>% mutate(across(all_of(num_vars_p), as.numeric))
```

Then I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
Problem while computing `..1 = across(all_of(num_vars_p), as.numeric)`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
```

I would like to have a function that gives me the column name of `pm` and the number of NAs that have been introduced.

Comment: `Error: object 'r23' not found`

Comment: Where `NA`s are introduced? Look in the data? Perhaps `pm[!complete.cases(pm),]`, as it will give you all rows with at least one `NA` in it.

Comment: Trying your code, I get an error, you sholdn't have `.keep_all=T` in your call to `full_join`

Comment: @Friede I had thought about that as well, but ... nothing would join since `ID` is a join key. (In which case finding `NA`s would be easier ... they're _everywhere_ :-).

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot the '' around the r23, r24 etc. I corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's fix two problems:

1. We don't have `r23` and friends, I'll replace them naïvely with `paste0("A", 1:4)` for the sake of your code; and
2. I'll remove `.keep_all=TRUE` from `full_join`; that isn't an argument for [`*_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html), and in recent versions of `dplyr` it is an error to have anything unexpected in the `...` portion of the call. I suspect it is either a carryover from a call to `distinct(..)`, or you intend `keep=TRUE` (which produces yet another error ... so likely not this).

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), depth = c("deep", "deep", "shallow", "shallow"), conc1 = c("3.0", "<1.0", "2.5", "10.0"), conc2 = c(23, 45, 56, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), depth2 = c("deep", "shallow", "shallow", "deep"), conc1 = c(5, 3.4, 5.2, 1.2), conc2 = c(56, 76, 45, 23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

num_vars_p <- df1 %>%
  select_if(function(x) is.numeric(x) | any(grepl("<[0-9]", x))) %>%
  names()
num_vars_p
# [1] "conc1" "conc2"

pm <- full_join(mutate(df1, across(everything(), as.character)),
                mutate(df2, across(everything(), as.character)),
                by = c("ID", "depth" = "depth2", "conc1", "conc2")) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(num_vars_p), as.numeric))
# Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
# ℹ In argument: `across(all_of(num_vars_p), as.numeric)`.
# Caused by warning:
# ! NAs introduced by coercion
```

With this, since it's small data, we can simply do `pm` and see that in this case row 2 `conc1` is `NA`. I'm assuming your data is larger, so we need an alternative.

Assuming that you expect no `NA` values *anywhere*, then you can simply use `complete.cases`:

```r
pm[!complete.cases(pm),]
#   ID depth conc1 conc2
# 2 A2  deep    NA    45
```

which conveniently retains its row number (`2`, because we aren't using dplyr here) and shows the errant column(s).

If you have too many columns and need to reduce to just those columns, then we can do:

```r
pm %>%
  filter(!complete.cases(pm)) %>%
  select(ID, where(anyNA))
#   ID conc1
# 1 A2    NA
```

(though we lost the row number to `dplyr`'s agressive de-row-numbering). I'm assuming `ID` is important to you here, if others are as well then they are easy enough to add.

If all you need to know is which rows or which columns, we can do

```r
### which rows
which(!complete.cases(pm))
# [1] 2

### which columns
sapply(pm, anyNA)
#    ID depth conc1 conc2 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 

### which cells
which(is.na(pm), arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   2   3

### total
sum(is.na(pm))
# [1] 1

### per-row/column counts
colSums(is.na(pm))
#    ID depth conc1 conc2 
#     0     0     1     0 
rowSums(is.na(pm))
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Ah, understood. Impressive research (cp. bullet point two).